# Spark AR Native UI Picker

Tags: spark-ar-studio

In Documentation page of Native UI Picker it says: 
"The NativeUI Picker is an interface you can add to effects. It allows people using your effect to **choose different options** within it by selecting icons.
For example the user can tap different icons to change the **texture** shown in the effect"

I've made several effects with NativeUI texture "switcher", and was trying to implement NativeUI to switch not between textures, but effects (objects) themselves.

For example if I would make a FaceMesh with some texture on it, that would change with a screen tap and a particle system with another texture also with a change when the screen is tapped. How could I switch between those two using NativeUI?

I don't really like my current solution to this because it's not user friendly. I've used PatchEditor and FaceFinder, turning on/off visibility of the faceMesh and Emitter when eyebrows are raised. See the screenshot bellow:

[image: Spark AR Patch Editor]
I would really appreciate any suggestions, 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
// Load in modules
const NativeUI = require("NativeUI");
const Textures = require("Textures");
const Patches = require("Patches");

export const Diagnostics = require("Diagnostics");

// Create a number
let userNumber = 0;

const texture0 = Textures.get("number1");
const texture1 = Textures.get("number2");
const texture2 = Textures.get("number3");

const index = 0;
const configuration = {
  selectedIndex: index,
  items: [
    { image_texture: texture0 },
    { image_texture: texture1 },
    { image_texture: texture2 }
  ]
};
const picker = NativeUI.picker;
picker.configure(configuration);
picker.visible = true;

picker.selectedIndex.monitor().subscribe(function(index) {
  userNumber = index.newValue;
  // Send the number to the Patch Editor under the name 'userNumber'
  Patches.setScalarValue("userNumber", userNumber);
  // Debugging
  Diagnostics.log("user selection = " + index.newValue);
});
```

Using NativeUI picker. The code above will output index value as userNumber(scalar) to patch editor.

Examples: 
If user pick number 1 the output of userNumber will be 0,
If user pick number 2 the output of userNumber will be 1,
If user pick number 3 the output of userNumber will be 2, 
etc.

You can use userNumber as switch combine with equal exactly
[NativeUI Picker as Switch Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GjYS.png)